# Changing text color of individual bar button items in navigation bar

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have two bar button items placed in the navigation bar, but I want to change the text color of one to show whether its enabled or disabled.  I've seen a lot of solutions for changing the text color for all navigation bar button items, but nothing for one specific bar button item.  Most solutions on SO seem to be deprecated for iOS7 and iOS8.  Any tips?

Comment: You could set the `titleView` property on the UINavigationItem to some custom view—in your case, maybe a UILabel displaying an NSAttributedString that you pass in.

Comment: You should probably actually disable it and set a style for disabled.

Comment: @bdesham Sorry for the confusion - these are UIBarButtonItems so there is no titleView property.